# Providing suggestions via Typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I have an app that uses Bootstrap, jQuery, [Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) and Azure Search. I'm trying to use the [suggestions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798936.aspx) feature. In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'https://my-app.search.windows.net/indexes/my-index/docs/suggest?api-version=2015-02-28',
    prepare: function (settings) {
      settings.type = 'POST';
      settings.contentType = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8';
      settings.data = { search: query, suggesterName: 'mySuggestions', top: 10 };                                                        
      return settings;
    }
  }
});

$('#searchField').typeahead([{
  minLength: 5,
  name: 'suggestions',
  source: engine
}]);
```

When I enter text into the searchField, I never see requests fired off to the Azure Search service in Fiddler. At the same time, I do not see any errors in the console window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things seem off to me.
First this:

```
$('#searchField').typeahead([{
  minLength: 5,
  name: 'suggestions',
  source: engine
}]);
```

Might need to be more like this:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null,{
  minLength: 5,
  source: engine
});
```

Also the prepare in your engine function needs to include the "query" arg.

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'https://my-app.search.windows.net/indexes/my-index/docs/suggest?api-version=2015-02-28',
    prepare: function (query,settings) {
      settings.type = 'POST';
      settings.contentType = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8';
      settings.data = { search: query, suggesterName: 'mySuggestions', top: 10 };                                                        
      return settings;
    }
  }
});
```

You can see a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/spz3gt3w/1/).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!